# Filter out nested array of objects in mongoose with its schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a student schema which has a skills field i.e. an array of objects.
for ex.

```js
{
    "badges": [],
    "projects": [
        "5ffaff96c7c6f43ec4e41e7e",
        "5ffc55666ec0103e5cb18e93",
        "5ffc562255c8545060088cff",
        "5ffd58f2892e675118d4df5a"
    ],
    "_id": "5ff9daf501a1e63674c20b58",
    "owner": "5ff9da9eefb10a15f4f7bfe1",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-09T16:33:57.721Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-13T09:07:08.339Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "github": "github",
    "linkedin": "linkedin",
    "twitter": "twitter",
    "personalBlog": "blog",
    "skills": [
        {
            "isActive": false,
            "_id": "5ffeb83ce0b57a3eac2a490f",
            "name": "HTML"
        },
        {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "5ffeb83ce0b57a3eac2a4910",
            "name": "CSS"
        },
        {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "5ffeb83ce0b57a3eac2a4911",
            "name": "CSS"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter out skills whose isActive fields are true. I tried each and every way but not able to find the solution.
I want student schema + skills whose isActive are true

Comment: your current condition will check `skills` has object `{ isActive: true }` or not, instead try this `{ "skills.isActive": true }`

Comment: already tried but didn't get it.